# Dynamic value in Custom Annotation

Tags: java

Is there a way I could pass in a dynamic value into a Custom Annotation?

For example as follows:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnot {
    String[] requestKeys();
}
```

When annotating, I want to pass in the value of the argument dynamically.

```
@CustomAnnot(requestKeys = {"id"}) // or maybe "#id"
public Object get(String id) {}
```

To note the above won't just work. Need some form of parsing for this to work.

How can I go about doing this? Trying to find online references and but unable to find anything to aid in this implementation.

@Cacheable in Spring is able to do this thus clearly this is possible. Tried to have a look  over the implementation for @Cacheable and to be honest got lost. It's massive and a struggle to debug. Could I get some advice on this implementation or if anyone familiar point to the part where cacheable implements this? Thanks.

EDIT:
I need a way to get values from arguments in a method.

Example.

```
// maybe in this method I only want String b and c
String method1(String a, String b, String c){
    return null;
}

// maybe here I want String a and c
String method2(int d, String a, String b, String c){
    return null;
}

// just 1 argument here so only need String a
String method3(String a){
    return null;
}
```

I am looking for a single way to get the values of what I need in 1 way. 
I want to write this functionality once and be done with it, not have to come back again for a different method signature.

Thus I was going for a custom annotation which gives me flexibility to decide what values I want so I can pass in an array .

Comment: Annotations aren't designed for runtime/dynamic values. If you share how you're using the value or the problem you're solving, people here may suggest what the right solution should be in the first place.

Comment: @ernest_k Added as an EDIT above to mention what I am trying to achieve, ultimate the annotation is supposed to go to an Aspect class which would use the argument values to perform some actions.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"pass in the value of the argument dynamically"* here, but in your example the array `{"id"}` is known at compile-time, because it's written as a literal in the code. It is not determined dynamically. The JLS forbids dynamically determining an argument for an annotation: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7

Comment: @kaya3 That could be the case but all I am saying is @ Cacheable does this. It has a 'key' which is able to read a cachekey value based on an argument's name so it is possible. Thus how is this done?

Comment: You are not explaining very well what you want to do, or what @ Cacheable does that other annotations don't, so I can't answer. I can guarantee that because @ Cacheable is an annotation, that its arguments cannot be determined by dynamically-evaluated expressions.